# In Mass Effect 3, is it possible to reach max level, 60, in one playthrough?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I will be importing a maxed character from ME2 and I want to get an idea of what will be needed to max at 60.

Ideally I would like to max in the first playthrough, if DLC is needed that's fine too.

So officially:  Using a maxed ME2 save and any day/week one DLC, is it possible to reach the max level of 60 without replaying content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes. if you imported a character at level 30 you can certainly reach 60 on the first playthrough.

FROM THE LEAD DESIGNER: ["You cannot reach level 60 without an ME2 import or NG+ in ME3"](https://twitter.com/#!/PWatamaniuk/status/167856656879849472)

Comment: Any possibility you could clarify? You've achieved 60 on a 30 starting level? or even less? Looking for absolute confirmation.

Comment: from the lead designer via twitter:
PWatamaniuk:
[2011/08/16][12:30:46]
Level 60. If you import you start with the same level you had at the end of ME2.

Comment: Could I please have a link?

Comment: this is his twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/PWatamaniuk

Answer (score 9):

I hit level 60 right at the final battle, and I was level 30 when I started the game. The trick was that I never used ANY medi-gel the entire game, so I got xp instead. That's about 150-450 xp per medi-gel you find, which really adds up over time. My final xp gain actually was from medi-gel, as a matter of fact. I did every mission in the game, plus the day 1 DLC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to reach level 60 on your first playthrough. Pretty much like Jason, I hit level 60 right on the final battle arena.

Requirements:

- Import a level 30 character from ME2;
- Play on Insanity (to get the most bonus from medi-gel containers)
- Refrain from using medigel, instead rely on reviving your squadmates manually, or even better don't letting them get killed, so that you get the most experience bonus from medi-gel containers;
- Playing the day 1 DLC is essential because of the extra XP.

Still, it's not so bad going through the game a 2nd or 3rd time. In fact, if you're aiming to get all of the achievements, you have to play it again anyway, because of the "Veteran" achievement (you know, the 5.000 kills milestone. Yep.)

Comment: To get the veteran achievements you can play multiplayer - your kills count. That is how i got it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reach level 59 during the final mission; finishing the game gives a certain amount of XP, which was enough to bump me up to level 60 and earn the achievement.

*However*, that level 60 is only useful during a New Game + playthrough; the post-finale save point the game creates (for playing DLC) puts you at the same level you were before you went to the point of no return (in my case I believe it was level 56).

I don't believe that it's possible to hit level 60 before the point of no return, even without using Medigel (I didn't use any), so you need to do a second playthrough if you want to play the forthcoming DLC at the level cap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible, I imported my ME2 character, did every single mission (including secondary missions), but ended up only on level 56.

Comment: Oh and I was lvl 30 in ME2

Comment: I've had the same experience. Got to level 56 in London.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I started on level 30 and reached level 60 right at the end of the game. I've played on insanity and like the others I did not use the medigel to get the 450 XP from the medigel containers. I did every mission in the game, and didn't play any DLC.